# How to get data from a row if a value in a different table is null

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, join, select, sql-in

I have a database I want to get data from. In order to get the not yet edited files, I want to create a CSV file which lists all the files if the age is NULL. This is the code I have written:

```
def make_csv():
    c,conn=connect()
    #get the id and name from the SERIES table if the age in the SERIES_METADATA table is null
    query="SELECT ID,NAME FROM FILES WHERE FILE_METADATA.AGE IS NULL"
    series_id={'series_id':[],'series_name':[]}
    c.execute(query)
    for row in c:
        series_id['series_id'].append(row[0])
        series_id['series_name'].append(row[1])
        #series_add.append(series_id)
        #print(series_id)
    conn.close()
    df=pd.DataFrame(series_id)
    df.to_csv('files_id-new.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

However, when I execute the code, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/GitHub/Program/dbcon.py", line 146, in <module>
    make_csv()
  File "/home/USER/GitHub/Program/dbcon.py", line 24, in make_csv
    c.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: FILE_METADATA.AGE
```

I know that something must be wrong, as the table FILE_METADATA exists, as well as the column AGE.

Did I write it wrongly or is this kind of operation not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in the table `FILE_METADATA` there is a column, say `file_id`, which is a foreign key referencing the column `id` in the table `FILES`.

In such a case, you can join the tables:

```
SELECT f.ID, f.NAME 
FROM FILES f INNER JOIN FILE_METADATA m
ON m.file_id = f.ID
WHERE m.AGE IS NULL;
```

or, with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM FILES
WHERE ID IN (SELECT file_id FROM FILE_METADATA WHERE AGE IS NULL);
```